# How to always format a value coming out as two decimal spaces in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.17 and am storing prices for items like this (an example migration):

```
add_column :item_counts, :per_item_cost, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

but if it's 23.00, it comes out as 23.0. I tend to create a method like this:

```
  def helpers
    ActionController::Base.helpers
  end

  def per_item_cost_formatted
    helpers.number_to_currency(per_item_cost, precision: 2, format: "%n")
  end
```

Is there a way I can specify that it always outputs formatted to be 23.00? Something like:

```
  def per_item_cost
    helpers.number_to_currency(per_item_cost, precision: 2, format: "%n")
  end
```

causes an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision):

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

def per_item_cost
  number_with_precision(read_attribute(:per_item_cost), precision: 2)
end
```

Comment: thx vee; hmm..... so doing something liek that gives me a 500 with `SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70` which is why I was naming it differently with the _formatted.

Comment: nice - thx vee; read_attribute did it; have to wait a few minutes

Comment: @timone, Great! Here is the documentation on [`read_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute)